# Google Play - "Issue: Incorrect content rating"

Tags: google-play, rating, google-play-console

My app is called "a Reason to Drink Today." Google rejects to publish due to alleged incorrect rating due to references to alcohol (the word "to drink"). They ask me to go through questionnaire again on the age rating (content rating). What item in that section is related to the mention of alcohol and how do I publish?
[Email from Google Play](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3Uad.png)
[My age rating settings (interface in Russian)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIFlG.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your app should be Adult rating, but you have choose any age, Before uploading app again

In store listing > app content > make it 18+

and in Content rating : example like this

[image]